# why top 5 with ties not giving complete record sets

Tags: sql-server-2008

My query result should give top 5 with ties records but the query mentioned below is giving 130,130,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120

but I want the result as
130,130,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,110,100

```
select top 5 with ties b.quantity
from dbo.Products as a
inner join dbo.[Order Details] as b
on a.productid = b.productid
inner join dbo.Suppliers as c
on c.supplierid = a.supplierid
order by quantity desc
```

I am not able to understand why the above query is not including 110 and 100 numbers even after including Top 5 with ties.

Comment: With no idea into the dataset that SHOULD return the 110 and 100, it's impossible to troubleshoot this. Maybe include the minimal rows that SHOULD return the 110 and 100 and that don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordered list is cut at the 5th row. But all rows with the same "rank" come in too, otherwise it would be rather random, which of them is included and which is not.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx#tie) about `TOP WITH TIES`,

> WITH TIES may cause more rows to be returned than the value specified
>   in expression. For example, if expression is set to 5 but 2 additional
>   rows match the values of the ORDER BY columns in row 5, the result set
>   will contain 7 rows.

In your example `ORDER BY quantity desc`gives the results as,

```
130
130
120
120
120
etc
```

You have specified TOP 5. Which means that the tied values in fifth row will be  retrieved by the SELECT query. Here 5th row is 120, so all the 120 will be retrieved.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a5bdd/1)

Comment: Yes you are correct. But my question is why 110 and 100 are not retrieved from the query. The Top 5 with ties should give numbers -  130,120,110,100. But the query is giving numbers - 130,120. I can clearly see I have more numbers like 110 and 100 but they are not included in the query. Because of this I have now taken  a different approach. I am now using dense_rank() instead of top 5 with ties

Comment: No, the `TOP 5 WITH TIES` does not  give 130, 120, 110 and 100. You are expecting `DISTINCT` values.

Comment: sorry for the confusion i ment output is coming as - 130,130,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120 but the correct output should be  - 130,130,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,120,110,100

Comment: I think that the ordered list is cut at the 5th row. But all rows with the same "rank" come in too, otherwise it would be rather random, which of them is included and which is not.

Comment: @Shnugo: Yes... now that makes sense. I will use dense_rank() instead...Thanks for clearing that confusion.